# Подскажите сборщики html для gulp

Tags: html, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

Подскажите, как можно подключать html файлы один в другой в определённом месте и как их сжимать в gulp?

Comment: Вы html-шаблонизатор **pug** пробовали?

Comment: @"Alexandr Kazakov" только что посмотрел, но не понял, как в нём просто вставить html в определённом месте? Всё остальное,как jade-подобное преобразование и др. в данном случае, мне не нужно.

Comment: **pug**, это и есть **jade** под новым названием(или я вас неправильно понял?)

Comment: @"Alexandr Kazakov" Можно ли в нём обработав файлы,вставить содержимое другого файла? Например <div>вставить содержимое из файла сюда {{c:\path.to.file.html}}</div>

Comment: Я сам новичок в нем, дабы не тратить ваше время зря и не вводить вас в заблуждение, скажу - не знаю.  Если вам важен вопрос про pug, я могу скинуть вам ссылку на vk, человека который его активно использует, у него спросите, он использует pug и gulp. Только я не знаю можно ли здесь такие ссылки давать

Comment: Один добрый человек мне здесь подсказал https://toster.ru/q/212315

Comment: Ставлю минус данному вопросу, т.к. в комментариях у меня не получилось выяснить подходит _pug_  или нет; под заданный вопрос он подходит; автор вопрос не правит и подробнее не описывает задачу, вопрос не дает развернутых объяснений и занимает полторы строки текста.

Comment: @"Alexandr Kazakov" я поискал в гугле статьи, как же всё-таки вставить содержимое файла и так и не нашёл.Если кто-то подскажет- как это сделать с pug либо как-то ещё - буду благодарен. И за +1 тоже)

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Касательно импорта html в html есть вот такие варианты
http://www.webmasters.by/articles/html-coding/3288-html5-imports.html
https://habrahabr.ru/post/230751/

Что касается импорта в pug, то тут возможно воспользоваться подгрузкой блока через AJAX